# Anonymous implementation of abstract classes in Rhino

Tags: java, javascript, scripting, abstract-class, rhino

I need to implement a listener in JavaScript by anonymous subclass of an existing abstract base class, defined like this:

```
public class Speaker {
  public static abstract class MyListener {
    private String name;
    public MyListener(final String name) { this.name = name; }
    public abstract boolean listen(final String words);
  }
}
```

In java, implementing a listener is done with anonymous subclasses:

```
MyListener newListener = new MyListener("George") {
  public boolean listen(final String words) throws Exception { Thread.sleep(500); }
}
```

If I try to do that in JavaScript, I can't call the constructor of the abstract base class and implement the virtual function at the same time.

It works if I remove the constructor argument, then a call to MyListener() with the method implementation as a parameter creates an instance of the subclass I need. But I actually need to call the constructor with **both** the constructor parameter **and** the method implementation.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you're trying to involve Javascript in this problem. Can you provide an example of what you tried that *doesn't* work?

Comment: I have a scriptable application written in Java. I can use the JS console for some operations (by calling methods of my application's classes). I want to write a script to handle some events of this application, but to do so I need to implement a listener.
What doesn't work: I cannot write "x = Speaker.MyListener("George", function(words) { sleep(); })" in Rhino: JS console gets an InvocationTargetException, and quits.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html#jsimplement

It's about implementing interfaces, but might be applicable.